# Node.js Command Prompt Issue

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, npm

I don't believe this behavior is correct at all, but please correct me if I'm mistaken. So I have an Angular 2/Ionic 2 app created all through the Node.js command prompt... the commands all work fine, up until I execute `ng serve`, after that I can't type at all into the command prompt. Only way I can type is if I close out of the command prompt and restart (less than ideal). Is this normal behavior? Or only occurring on my machine?

Comment: Did you press CTRL + C to stop execution? ng serve is a loop that must be broken before you can type again. If you're trying to add components with "ng g c" or anything like that while the app is running, then you will have to open another cmd prompt.

Comment: Thank you! @BrandonMiller I couldn't find anything on this subject anywhere. It makes sense to break up the loop before executing any more commands, just would've thought this would've been mentioned in the angular/node/ionic documentation at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng serve` launches a basic web server for you using which your static files are served. It also listens for updates to your project files and if any changes are detected it bundles the project again and reloads the browser tab automatically. So it's important that it keeps running when you're developing your application.